# how to change params that vue use plugin at components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

example the main.js

```
import clampy from '@clampy-js/vue-clampy'
Vue.use(clampy)
```

at Component.vue

```
import clampy from '@clampy-js/vue-clampy'
Vue.use(clampy,{
    truncationChar: 'xxx',
})
```

but this is not working, Vue.use automatically prevents you from using the same plugin more than once, so calling it multiple times on the same plugin will install the plugin only once.
so how to make it

Comment: same question here :(